Issue with Sending WebSocket Messages Using SiLab RS9116
I am using the RS9116 API for WebSocket communication. Here is a detailed explanation of the issue I am facing:

WebSocket is created using rsi_web_socket_create (works fine).
Data reception after socket creation (works fine).
Sending feedback data in response to the received data using the rsi_web_socket_send_async function.
Checked the return value, and it is normal (as per the API documentation, it returns the number of bytes sent when the transmission is successful).
Sending the second piece of data.
Socket terminates unexpectedly <-- this is the issue.
6-1. The error message states: "A new message was started when a continuation frame was expected."

I don't understand what the message in 6-1 means. Since the return value indicates successful transmission, I'm not sure what I should be doing differently.
Given that data reception works correctly, the socket creation seems to be functioning normally.
For more information on the SiLab API,
here is the link: https://docs.silabs.com/rs9116-wiseconnect/2.9.1/wifibt-wc-sapi-reference/network5#rsi-web-socket-send-async
I suspected this might be an issue with the WebSocket data framing, so I attempted to manage the opcode and mask before sending the data. However, I received an error indicating that UTF-8 decoding was not possible, leading me to believe this is not the core issue.

Can you share a code snippet? See section 10.10.9.2 here: https://manuals.plus/m/af35dc4020883060ebc8c0ca1c5a4042db507bb2757cbda4358778e10588ed41
How are you setting the "opcode" field for both messages? The website indicates the "opcode" must be "0" to indicate a continuation frame, i.e. make sure this is "0" for the second packet.

This is the code when transmitting data.
uint8_t data[] = "Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello\0";
send_len = strlen(data);
//tt_start = rsi_hal_gettickcount();
status = rsi_web_socket_send_async( g_iClient_socket, 0x1, data, send_len );
if (status < 0){ GLogE( "Error... Fail Send(0x%04X)\r\n", status );
{
//rsi_shutdown(g_iClient_socket, 0);
//GLogN( "rsi_shutdown(g_iClient_socket) \n\r" );
}
else
GLogE( "Send length : %d\r\n", status );

@이재석 You can edit your original post, and paste your code inside.
